# Python overriding a method but using old version in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, overriding

I have a simple (I guess problem). Basically I want to use [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) mouse (`pynput.mouse.Controller`) to make my own class. So I did this:

```
from pynput.mouse import Controller as ms
from pynput.mouse import Button as btn

Button = btn


class Mouse(ms):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        curX, curY = self.position
        print(curX, curY)
        ms.move(dx - curX, dy - curY)

    def move_click(self, x, y, button):
        pass
```

The problem occurs in `move` method. It overrides a method from `Controller` which is `move(self, dx, dy)`. I wanted to override it, cause it uses relative pixel coordinates, I want to use absolute coordinates.

So I do the calculation `(dx - curX, dy - curY)` and I want to pass those to the old version of `move`, so I don't call my own class' `move`, I call `move` from the imported `Controller`.

I wrote the code to check this:

```
from mouse import Mouse, Button

def main():
    mouse = Mouse()
    mouse.move(0, 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error I get is this:

```
C:\projects\python\test\mouse>python main.py
649 157
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 6, in main
    mouse.move(0, 0)
  File "C:\projects\python\test\mouse\mouse.py", line 14, in move
    ms.move(dx - curX, dy - curY)
TypeError: move() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dy'
```

So what am I doing wrong? Should I change the way I import stuff, or maybe the thing I want to do is impossible?

Comment: You need to pass `self`.

Comment: Use `super`, as you do for `__init__`: `super().move(dx - curX, dy - curY)`.

Comment: `ms.move` is an instance method, declared (just like yours) as `def move(self, x, y):`, right? You call it directly on the class, without passing one of the parameters. Even better, use `super()` to access the overridden method.

Comment: (Also, `from pynput.mouse import Button as btn; Button = btn` is same as `from pynput.mouse import Button`, no? Why the `btn` thing?)

Comment: Yes, but then the linter does not complain about unused import :( And yes, guys, you were right. Using `super()` is a fancy trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I'll parrot the responses from the comments above, and try to answer this question generally for anyone else that happens upon this.

If the parent class is called `Parent`, and you hope to override its method called `foo()`, this is a template of how to do that:

```py
class Child(Parent):
    def foo(*args, **kwargs):
        return super().foo(*args, **kwargs)
```

Of course, this template as written would not behave any differently from never overriding `foo()` at all, but the point is that you'd want to change it to your specifications (e.g., include additional parameters, adjust return value, etc).

Comment: You should use `super` instead as that will search correctly through the mro.